# Как из строки получить подстроку по регулярному выражению PHP

Tags: php

Есть строка с HTML кодом и регулярка, которая находит все h3 заголовки. Но не могу найти в php функцию, которая возвращает подстроку по регулярному выражению. Такая функция вообще есть в PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php

Comment: @Mike preg_match() возвращает 1, если параметр pattern соответствует переданному параметру subject, 0 если нет, или FALSE в случае ошибки.Эта функция не возвращает строку

Comment: @Dantessss А вы повнимательнее документацию прочитайте про preg_match. Особенно про параметры ее.

Comment: @Dantessss Внимательнее прочтите описание preg_match, особенно обратите внимание на третий параметр "matches" - это массив в который будут возвращены совпадения !

Comment: @ rjhdby Да спасибо, не заметил про дополнительный параметр, куда передается строка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавлю к **@rjhdby** и **@Mike**.

Воспользуйтесь функцией `preg_match()`.

```
<?php
$str = "123 234 345 456 567";                       // Строка для поиска
$result = preg_match('/\d{3}/',$str,$found);        // Производим поиск
echo "Matches: $result<br>";                        // Выводим количество найденных совпадений
print_r($found);                                    // Выводим результат поиска

# Output:
Matches: 1

Array
(
    [0] => 123
)
?>
```

Источник: [этот сайт.](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=regexp&page=007)